# PgAdmin4 does not restore previous environment

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin3

There was a nice feature in pgAdmin3 that automatically restored the previous environment while connecting to a server. It seems to be missing in pgAdmin4 though or is somehow deactivated by default. (anyway, can somebody with a reputation higher that 300 points create such a tag?).

Has anyone faced a similar problem with pgAdmin4 and knows how to configure it, so that it restores previous environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature seems to be back from version 4.2 of pgAdmin4.